# Why does nm-applet icon still animated after connection?

Tags: network-manager, indicator

I am running Ubuntu 15.04. From time to time, the nm-applet icon (in the upper right part of the screen) keeps animated, even after the wifi network is connected and working fine. It does not seem to impact network operation, but is annoying. I've tried to kill nm-applet and restart it, but the symptom remains: the wifi network is still connected and the icon still animated. What else could I try to solve this problem?

Comment: Not at all. The signal strength is quite good, and I am close to the base station.

Comment: I have the exact same problem!  Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in Ubuntu 15.04, and while I do not have the solution to the underlying problem, I find the following usually puts a stop to that annoying animation without having to restart the computer:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```